# Why Using GeohayStack fail

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I run this query in mongo shell, and successful get result

```
db.tablebusiness.find({ "LongitudeLatitude" : { "$near" : [106.772835, -6.186753], "$maxDistance" : 0.053980478460939611 }, "indexContents" : { "$all" : [/^warung/] } }).limit(2);
```

I got:

```
{
  "_id" : "warung-nasi-nur-karomah__-6.19_106.78",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Warung Nasi Nur Karomah",
  "InBuildingAddress" : null,
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl. Arjuna Utara No.35",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Jakarta",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 45.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 106.775693893433,
    "Latitude" : -6.18759540055471
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 0.0,
    "Weight" : 0.0
  },
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : null,
  "Tags" : ["Restaurant"],
  "Phones" : ["081380087011"],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "warung", "arung", "rung", "ung", "ng", "g", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "nur", "ur", "r", "karomah", "aromah", "romah", "omah", "mah", "ah", "h"]
}
```

But when I try this query with additional search multikey index  I got nothing result

```
db.runCommand({ geoSearch : "tablebusiness", near : [106.772835, -6.186753], maxDistance : 0.053980478460939611, search : { "indexContents" : { "$all" : [/^warung/] } }, limit : 30 })
```

I got this

```
{
        "results" : [ ],
        "stats" : {
                "time" : 0,
                "btreeMatches" : 0,
                "n" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

This is index in my collection database

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "LongitudeLatitude" : "2d",
                        "Prominent" : -1,
                        "indexContents" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "LongLat_Prominent_indexContents",
                "dropDups" : false,
                "background" : false
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "LongitudeLatitude" : "2d",
                        "Prominent" : -1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "LongLat_Prominent",
                "dropDups" : false,
                "background" : false
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "indexContents" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "indexContents",
                "dropDups" : false,
                "background" : false
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "LongitudeLatitude" : "2d",
                        "indexContents" : 1,
                        "Prominent" : -1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "LongitudeLatitude__indexContents_1_Prominent_-1",
                "bits" : 22
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "Title" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "Title",
                "dropDups" : false,
                "background" : false
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "City" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "City",
                "dropDups" : false,
                "background" : false
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "LongitudeLatitude" : "geoHaystack",
                        "indexContents" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "isikotacobacoba.tablebusiness",
                "name" : "LongitudeLatitude__indexContents_1",
                "bucketSize" : 0.1
        }
]
```

How format use runCommand mongoDB using geohaystack with additional field mulikey??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geohaystack queries do not support arrays for the additional field,
only single values. The current implementation of geospatial indexes
and geohaystacks do not use the standard query and index code.

The examples from MongoDB's geohaystack documentation (
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Haystack+Indexing )
only shows the additional field to be a simple single value, not an
array of values in a geohaystack query.